# Capybara + Downloading and using file

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm using Capybara to navigate through a login on a website and then download a few files (I'm automating a frequent process that I have to do). There's a few things I tried that aren't working and I'm hoping someone might know a solution...

1. I have the two links I'm executing .click on, but while one file will start downloading (this is using the Chrome Selenium driver), capybara seems to stop functioning after that. Running .click on the other link doesn't do anything... I figured it's because it's not technically on the page anymore (since it followed a download link) but I tried revisiting the page to click the second link and that doesn't work either.

   2. Assuming I can get that working, I'd really like to be able to download to my script location rather than my Downloads folder, but I've tried every profile configuration I've found online and nothing seems to change it.
   3. Because of the first two issues, I decided to try wget... but I would need to continue from the session in capybara to authenticate. Is it possible to pull the session data (just cookies?) from capybara and insert it into a wget or curl command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For #3 - accessing the cookies is driver dependent - in selenium it's

```
page.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies
```

or you can use the https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies gem which normalizes access across most of Capybaras drivers.  With those cookies you can write them out to a file and then use the `--load-cookies` option of wget (`--cookie` option in curl)

For #1 you'd need to provide more info about any errors you get, what is current_url, what does "doesn't work" actually mean, etc

Comment: Exporting the cookies sounds like the best way then, and page.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies has my cookies in a hash, but how do I get that to a cookies.txt format? I've been googling the Mozilla format but I can't find any gem that supports conversion.. do I need to write my own?

Comment: @Max Yes you'd need to write them out yourself -- https://xiix.wordpress.com/2006/03/23/mozillafirefox-cookie-format/ is an article that explains the format, it's pretty basic.